# asp.net mvc 4 bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

How to add bootstrap to asp.net mvc 4?
I have installed through nudget bootstrap and I have also included in Bundle.config the following:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
                                "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
```

I have also included

```
"~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"
```

I have also included in Shared _layout the following

```
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/otf")     
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

The problem is how to make my table in Views/Home/index such as that of bootstrap page.I do include the

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Where did you include "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js", "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" scripts? You have to render this script after jquery scripts. And you don't need both bootstrap scripts. Include only bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js

Comment: place `<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` in your head tags

Comment: @DatoMaisuradze I included them at BundleConfig.cs  `code 'bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/otf").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/otf.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"
                    ));`

Comment: @DylanKilkenny It works Thanks You!

Comment: @DylanKilkenny unfortunatelly it does not output the one that I specified int the thead element.it gets style but not the one that I want! take a look at my _partial:`code <head><link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><div id="kjo"><div class="pagedList" data-otf-target="#kjo">@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page =>Url.Action("Index", new {page}),PagedList.Mvc.PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText)</div> <table class="table"><thead class="thead-inverse">

Comment: what  is the style you want and what is it displaying. Also you are missing your body tags

Comment: No,i Works Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Add The Packages From NUGet Package Manager Which is present in the tools option of Your Visual Studion. Now You Can Add The bootstrap file directly to the View using Script Or Link tags.

```
<link href="~/Content/Bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<script src="~/Script/Bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I did not found any thing good in touching bundle for this.

Answer (score 0):

place in your head tags

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```